# how spring aop handle @Transactional with jdk proxy?

Tags: java, spring

If one Service class has method with @Transactional, then spring will use proxy to handle it.
But if one Transactional method call another one

```
@Transactional
public FeedBackModel getOne() {
    ///..
    return getTwo();
}
@Transactional
public FeedBackModel getTwo() {
    return null;
}
```

like this.

if it is jdk proxy, then second @Transactional will not work.
But spring PROPAGATION will handle this correctly.
How it works?

Comment: what do you mean by spring PROPAGATION ? Transaction propagation has nothing to do with how spring proxy works.

Comment: @JEY why？when enter one method, how spring knows current method's transaction propagation

Comment: Because there is a transaction manager that keep track of it. I'll suggest that you read more about transaction in spring https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction

Comment: @JEY ok, thx~, i will read it

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to commit a transaction in `getTwo()` which is called from `getOne()`, that will not work, not even when both are @Transactional. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html):

> ...please do take the Spring team's advice and only annotate concrete
> classes (and the methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional
> annotation.
>
> Note: Since this mechanism is based on proxies, only 'external' method
> calls coming in through the proxy will be intercepted. This means that
> **'self-invocation'**, i.e. a method within the target object calling some
> other method of the target object, **won't lead to an actual transaction**
> at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional!